# Variable delay before updating an android textview

Tags: android, time, textview, delay, sensors

I have been trying to solve this problem for 9 hours straight, but nothing seems to work. I am building an app that captures values for all the available sensors in an Android phone over a certain time period, and stores these values in a remote database.
Two things should be kept in mind:

1. Each sensor has its own capture frequency (i.e. accelerometer each 10 seconds, gyroscope each 5 seconds, proximity each 60 seconds etc...).
2. This process doesn't go indefinitely, so there is a variable called duration, that specifies the total time spent capturing values. For example, if *acctime* = 10 and *duration* = 60, then we'll end up with 7 values captured at the 0s, 10s, 20s, 30s, 40s, 50s and 60s marks.

OK now for the code:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
     Sensor s = event.sensor;
     if (s.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
     {
          acc1 = event.values[0];
          acc2 = event.values[1];
          acc3 = event.values[2];
          accm = (float) Math.sqrt(acc1 * acc1 + acc2 * acc2 + acc3 * acc3);
     }
}
```

In the code above, the values are stored into their respective variables successfully.
Next, I want to display these variables in a textview, and update the textview as specified before (according to the frequency and total duration):

```
public void capture(View view) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        for (i = 0; i < duration; i++) {
            if ((i+1) % acctime == 0) {
                acc1 = Float.valueOf(df.format(acc1));  
                acc2 = Float.valueOf(df.format(acc2));
                acc3 = Float.valueOf(df.format(acc3));
                accm = Float.valueOf(df.format(accm));
                acctext.setText("i: " + i + "\nAccelerometer:\n\nX: " + acc1
                        + "\nY: " + acc2 + "\nZ: " + acc3 + "\nMagnitude: "
                        + accm);

            }
        }
    }
```

Here, the test `if (i % acctime == 0)` guarantees that the textview is updated whenever i is a multiple of acctime, which is precisely what we want: so for example if acctime = 10, the textview is updated when i = 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and 60.

However, for the life of me, I couldn't figure out how pause the loop for 1 second before proceeding (assign to i a time value of 1 second means that the loop makes sense, going from 0 to duration), so all that's left is pause the loop for 1 second.

I tried `Thread.Sleep(1000)` between a try/catch block, but it didn't work (it crashed).

The same happened for `android.os.SystemClock.sleep(1000);` .

I also found some code that looks like

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
     handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      //insert code here
    }
}, 1000);
```

Either it didn't work, or I am implementing something incorrectly. 
Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the full version of the function, and it's the version that makes sense the most to me. Please point out any errors that you can find:

```
public void capture(View view) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= duration) {
            if (acctime != -1 && (i % acctime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                acc1 = Float.valueOf(df.format(acc1));
                acc2 = Float.valueOf(df.format(acc2));
                acc3 = Float.valueOf(df.format(acc3));
                accm = Float.valueOf(df.format(accm));
                acctext.setText("Accelerometer:\n\nX: " + acc1 + "\nY: " + acc2
                        + "\nZ: " + acc3 + "\nMagnitude: " + accm);
            }
            if (magtime != -1 && (i % magtime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                mag1 = Float.valueOf(df.format(mag1));
                mag2 = Float.valueOf(df.format(mag2));
                mag3 = Float.valueOf(df.format(mag3));
                magm = Float.valueOf(df.format(magm));
                magtext.setText("Magnetometer\n\nX: " + mag1 + "\nY: " + mag2
                        + "\nZ: " + mag3 + "\nMagnitude: " + magm);
            }
            if (proxtime != -1 && (i % proxtime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                prox = Float.valueOf(df.format(prox));
                proxtext.setText("Proximity\n\nMagnitude: " + prox);
            }
            if (lighttime != -1 && (i % lighttime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                light = Float.valueOf(df.format(light));
                lighttext.setText("Light:\n\nMagnitude: " + light);
            }
            if (presstime != -1 && (i % presstime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                pressure = Float.valueOf(df.format(pressure));
                presstext.setText("Pressure:\n\nMagnitude: " + pressure);
            }
            if (gyrotime != -1 && (i % gyrotime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                gyro1 = Float.valueOf(df.format(gyro1));
                gyro2 = Float.valueOf(df.format(gyro2));
                gyro3 = Float.valueOf(df.format(gyro3));
                gyrom = Float.valueOf(df.format(gyrom));
                gyrotext.setText("Gyroscope:\n\nX: " + gyro1 + "\nY: " + gyro2
                        + "\nZ: " + gyro3 + "\nMagnitude: " + gyrom);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show logcat error from crash? are you handling the textview from a ui thread?

Comment: I am handling the textview from the code of the activity that I'm currently using/displaying on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `Handler` as follows to delay for 1sec.

```
int i = 1;
public void capture(View view) {
    final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");


    Handler handler = new Handler();

    while (i <= duration) {

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (acctime != -1 && (i % acctime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                    acc1 = Float.valueOf(df.format(acc1));
                    acc2 = Float.valueOf(df.format(acc2));
                    acc3 = Float.valueOf(df.format(acc3));
                    accm = Float.valueOf(df.format(accm));
                    acctext.setText("Accelerometer:\n\nX: " + acc1
                            + "\nY: " + acc2 + "\nZ: " + acc3
                            + "\nMagnitude: " + accm);
                }
                if (magtime != -1 && (i % magtime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                    mag1 = Float.valueOf(df.format(mag1));
                    mag2 = Float.valueOf(df.format(mag2));
                    mag3 = Float.valueOf(df.format(mag3));
                    magm = Float.valueOf(df.format(magm));
                    magtext.setText("Magnetometer\n\nX: " + mag1 + "\nY: "
                            + mag2 + "\nZ: " + mag3 + "\nMagnitude: "
                            + magm);
                }
                if (proxtime != -1 && (i % proxtime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                    prox = Float.valueOf(df.format(prox));
                    proxtext.setText("Proximity\n\nMagnitude: " + prox);
                }
                if (lighttime != -1 && (i % lighttime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                    light = Float.valueOf(df.format(light));
                    lighttext.setText("Light:\n\nMagnitude: " + light);
                }
                if (presstime != -1 && (i % presstime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                    pressure = Float.valueOf(df.format(pressure));
                    presstext
                            .setText("Pressure:\n\nMagnitude: " + pressure);
                }
                if (gyrotime != -1 && (i % gyrotime == 0 || i == 1)) {
                    gyro1 = Float.valueOf(df.format(gyro1));
                    gyro2 = Float.valueOf(df.format(gyro2));
                    gyro3 = Float.valueOf(df.format(gyro3));
                    gyrom = Float.valueOf(df.format(gyrom));
                    gyrotext.setText("Gyroscope:\n\nX: " + gyro1 + "\nY: "
                            + gyro2 + "\nZ: " + gyro3 + "\nMagnitude: "
                            + gyrom);
                }

                i++;
            }

        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I ran your code, and the application froze for around 1 minute (duration was 30 seconds), and then it crashed. Anything I can provide you with in order to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: Please any help would be greatly appreciated... I'm kinda stuck :S